# using 'in.' in the android app id (eg. in.example.myapp)

Tags: android, app-id

I wanted to know whether I can use 'in.' in  in the app id.

For example.. can i create my app id like this

in.example.myapp

As I am unable to create it using cordova CLI. But I have changed it in the config.xml

here is the error i am getting

```
cordova create MyApp in.example.myapp MyApp -d
CordovaError: App id contains a reserved word, or is not a valid identifier.
    at C:\Users\USer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\create.js:106:19
    at Promise.apply (C:\Users\USer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:1078:26)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\USer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:741:41)
    at C:\Users\USer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:1304:14
    at flush (C:\Users\USer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Can I publish such app on play store?

Please reply guys..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From official documentation:

> A full Java-language-style package name for the application. The name
>   should be unique. The name may contain uppercase or lowercase letters
>   ('A' through 'Z'), numbers, and underscores ('_'). However, individual
>   package name parts may only start with letters.
>
> To avoid conflicts with other developers, you should use Internet
>   domain ownership as the basis for your package names (in reverse). For
>   example, applications published by Google start with com.google. You
>   should also never use the com.example namespace when publishing your
>   applications.
>
> The package name serves as a unique identifier for the application.
>   It's also the default name for the application process (see the
>    element's process process attribute) and the default
>   task affinity of an activity (see the  element's
>   taskAffinity attribute).
>
> Caution: Once you publish your application, you cannot change the
>   package name. The package name defines your application's identity, so
>   if you change it, then it is considered to be a different application
>   and users of the previous version cannot update to the new version.

yes, you can use "in." on it... the "com." thing is like a domain ownership, that's all. Read: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

EDIT: This is Cordova documentation

> The  element's id attribute provides the app's reverse-domain
>   identifier, and the version its full version number expressed in
>   major/minor/patch notation.

Is not an Android limitation neither Play Store limitation if is Cordova limitation there is nothing you could do... if not, post the error; but, again... is not an Android/Play Store limitation.

Comment: then why am i not able to create it using cordova?

Comment: well... it looks like "in" is reserved, did you try (just for test) things like "org/my/app/" or similar?

Comment: i created the project successfully with app.example.myapp.. I hope this is ok with the play store and google rules..

Comment: yes :) you won't have an issue with that... but remember, you must use the same package name forever (with that app) so you can keep posting updates.

Answer (score 3):

"in" is a [reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) in Javascript. Since Cordova is built using JS, you can't use it in your package name. As noted by Mariano above, it is not an Android/Play Store limitation.

[Here's a list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar) of all reserved keywords:

> break case class catch const continue debugger default delete do else
>   export extends finally for function if import in instanceof let new
>   return super switch this throw try typeof var void while with yield

Comment: so how should i proceed

Comment: Don't use reserved keywords! Use ´com.example.myapp´ instead (assuming you own the myapp.example.com domain)

Comment: no.. i mean what should i do now.. my domain name ends with .in  I dont have .com domain

Comment: Well, one (ugly) way to do it would be to use an imaginary tld, like "app.example.myapp"

Comment: oh good.. but is it against any rules of google or play store?

Comment: I don't think using imaginary TLDs is against any rules